# Block retaining self for CGFloat ivars?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, ivar

I have a class with an ivar like this:

```
@interface MCProgressBarView() {
  CGFloat minimumForegroundWidth;
  CGFloat availableWidth;
}
```

later in code, I have this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    CGRect frame = _foregroundImageView.frame;
    frame.size.width = roundf(minimumForegroundWidth + availableWidth * valor);
    _foregroundImageView.frame = frame;

    [self layoutIfNeeded];

});
```

The `minimumForegroundWidth` line of this later code shows this error:

> Block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate
>   this is intended behavior

I know how to solve this for properties but what about CGFloat ivars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is `self->minimumForegroundWidth`. Arrow rather than dot. It's going back to the fact that `self` is actually a pointer to struct, and `->` is the the C notation for referencing members of that.

Comment: that is strange because it is a C notation but it works. THANKS.

Comment: Objective-C is just C… :D (Well, until ObjC2 and ARC, but it's still *mostly* C.)

Answer (score 2):

> I know how to solve this for properties but what about `CGFloat` ivars

As you know, the solution for properties is `weakSelf` pattern:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CGFloat localVar = weakSelf.property;
    ...
});
```

The solution for ivars is very similar except you need to explicitly check to see if `weakSelf` is `nil` or not, because you cannot dereference an ivar from `nil` pointer. So you create a strong local reference to your `weakSelf` and then check to see if it’s not `nil`:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        CGFloat localVar = strongSelf->ivar;
    }
});
```

---

Obviously, in your example, we generally wouldn’t worry about strong reference cycles (because the cycle is resolved as soon as the block finishes) and just use `self->minimumForegroundWidth` syntax to silence the warning. But the above `weakSelf` patterns are important where strong reference cycles are possible (e.g., you’re saving the block in a property, using it for repeating timer, etc.).